# How to swipe to next layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe

I'm searching about it over 2 days and couldn't find anything fits my projects.

I have a lot of buttons and text views in my layout. When i swipe the page i want it to go next layout.

I looked for view switcher, view flipper and view pager on internet, i searched tons of example, but any of them doesn't fit my project. How can i do that swipe? any basic tutorial, or methods for this? help me about it...

this will be my first layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLBxn.jpg
and this is my second layout https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZnY9.jpg

Comment: Search about `ViewPager` in Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlay your layout with a gesturelayout and then intercept its touch listeners to other layouts

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html

Comment: You can refer http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to swipe different layouts on github there is a library from daimaja which you can try.
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout